# PHP Return by reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

```
<?php

Class A {
    public static array $data = ["a" => [0, 1], "c" => [10, 1]];
    
    public static function getData($a): array {
        return self::$data[$a];
    }
}

// FIRST
print_r(A::$data);
print("<BR>");

// SECOND
$c = A::getData("c");
$c[0] = [20];
print_r(A::$data);
print("<BR>");

// THIRD
A::$data["c"] = [20];
print_r(A::$data);
print("<BR>");
```

RESULT 
Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) [c] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 1 ) )
Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) [c] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 1 ) )
Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) [c] => Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 1 ) )

SECOND didn't work.
So I changed `getData($a)` with `&getData($a)`
But still not solved.
WHY?
Wasn't it "return by reference" error?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Regardless of whether it *can* be accomplished by some variation of references, it would be very unusual behaviour for PHP arrays to behave like this, so you *shouldn't* design your "API" like this.

Comment: @deceze Then, how should I design it..?

Comment: With something more explicit like `A:setSomething($foo, $bar)`…? If you "need" to modify returned elements, you pretty much must use objects instead.

Comment: Aha! Ok, thanks. I'll design like that. But I'll leave a question open. Because I am still curious about the answer to the reference problem.